# moment().format(...) returns local time on some devices and UTC on other devices

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I have a cordova app. To load data from a server, I send as parameters the local time and the Unix timestamp:

```
var timestamp = Math.floor(date.getTime() / 1000);
var localtime = moment().format("YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss");
```

Now I saw that on some devices, localtime is not "local time" but it looks like UTC. From my logs:

```
2017-11-28 08:33:08 [...] URL/timestamp/1511879588/localtime/2017-11-28T14:33:08
```

The first date/time is "Chicago" (GMT-6), but the device was in New York (GMT-5) and on a screenshot I saw that it shows 9:33 as time (in the Android system), so this is correct.

On my devices (Android and iOS), localtime is correct, i.e., the same as the system time.

What could be wrong here, why is it sometimes "local time" and sometimes UTC?

Comment: `moment()` by default considers local timezone(which is system time zone) unless and until specified to consider utc by calling `moment().utc()`, more info available here,https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/utc/

Comment: This is why I am wondering...

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
var timestamp = Math.floor(date.getTime() / 1000);
var localtime = moment.parseZone(new Date()).local().format("YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss");
```